# Writing EXIF metadata to JPEG in Java

Tags: java, gps, metadata, exif

I want to edit GPS tag and save new GPS latitude and longitude to JPEG. Ok I found a [Sanselan Java library](http://commons.apache.org/imaging/)  which lets to do it. There is an example how to write metadata [WriteExifMetadataExample](http://massapi.com/source/sanselan-0.97-incubator/src/test/java/org/apache/sanselan/sampleUsage/WriteExifMetadataExample.java.html) end I used  changeExifMetadata(File jpegImageFile, File dst)
method. It works but this example creates a new photo with new gps latitude/longitude. I would like to set new GPS values on the same photo, how can I do this ?

Generally I want to create application similar to Picasa (photo viewer + google maps) .. and in this case when I drag and drop marker on map I want to save new gps exif metadata to photo.. so according with this example it will be create new photo every time? stupid ...I have a little experience with Java .. any sygestion/example is very usefull for me :)

Comment: Just save updated file with the same name and remove the original one. Why not?

Comment: @loki2302 JPEG is a lossy format. If it's copying and rewriting the whole image, the image quality could degrade. This could be a problem since it sounds like a repeatable user action triggers the change.

Comment: Writing or updating metadata won't degrade the  original image unless decompressing and re-compressing is involved.