# update and save metadata of an image file in java

Tags: java, image-processing, metadata, bufferedimage

I upload a jpg format image file from my computer and print all it's metadata.      now I update some metadata which was not there in the image. Now i want to add my given metadata to that image. How can i do that.

Now i have to write this metadata to the image file Test.jpg. Any leads ?

Comment: You'd have to read the image and write it to a file again - you can't just update the metadata and leave the rest unchanged.

Comment: @Thomas That depends on what metadata we're talking about. For example, it's possible to update most of the Exif data of a JPEG, COM markers etc, without decoding and re-encoding the JPEG data stream.

Comment: What (exactly) is it you are trying to do? What metadata do you want to update? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @haraldK I see, good to know :)

Comment: Duplicate question, already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487141/writing-exif-metadata-to-jpeg-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and copied exif data with [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) via command line execution from java